# Triangulations that are not manifolds?

Tags: differential-topology, triangulation

Any differentiable manifold can be [triangulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_(topology)) (and it can be done piecewise-linearly), but I get the impression that the converse is false. For insight, is there a good example of a topological space that can be triangulated but is not a differentiable manifold? If we know that a space can be triangulated, is there some set of additional assumptions under which we can say that it's a manifold?

Comment: Here's a simplicial complex that is not a manifold: $\bowtie$.

Comment: @RobArthan: I think that could have been an awesome one-character comment, although the SE software would probably not have allowed it :-) I would still be interested in understanding if there are additional assumption that would make it work.

Comment: @BenCrowell What do you mean by a manifold? A topological manifold? A PL manifold?.....

Comment: @MoisheCohen: I would happy to know any set of additional assumptions that would guarantee it to be any specific type of manifold.

Comment: @BenCrowell If links are topological spheres, the complex is a topological manifold.

Comment: @MoisheCohen: Oh, I see -- that's what a PL manifold is, right? If you feel like making that comment into an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instance, if links in the complex are triangulated spheres, then the complex is a PL manifold. However, even if links are not spheres, the complex might still be homeomorphic to a topological manifold (the double suspension of a 3-manifold which is a homology 3-sphere is a classical example).